# Query Optimization for added value

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a query that's behaving a bit oddly.  In my database I have a table called "records".  It tells me a bunch of information about what applications a user ran on my company's machines.  I'm trying to aggregate some statistics, but am having some odd issues with a query.

This query runs in about 6.5 minutes (~30 million entries in "records").  I would expect it to take longer when divisionName isn't specified, but it seems to be taking an unreasonable amount of time to finish (overnight and still chugging).

```
select divisionName, programName, count(usageID) 
    from records R 
    right join Programs P 
        on P.programID=R.usageProgramID 
    right join locate L 
        on L.computerID=R.usageComputerID 
    where divisionName="umbrella"
    group by programName
    order by programName asc
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/lab_prog_umbrella.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Is there an alternate structure to speed up the query?  I have an index on (computerID,divisionName) in locate and (programID,programName) in Programs as well as a multitude of indexes in records.

Note:
Programs contains 4 fields and locate contains 2.  I don't think the joins are exceptionally large.

**Edit:**

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys   | key       | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | L     | ref  | loc             | loc       | 27      | const                | 1195 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | R     | ref  | uprog,computers | computers | 34      | scf.L.computerID     | 1627 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | ref  | pid_name        | pid_name  | 43      | scf.R.usageProgramID |    1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Records Description:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| usageID         | varchar(24) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| usageWhen       | datetime    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| usageEnum       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageServerID   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageServerType | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageProgramID  | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| usageLicenseID  | varchar(18) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageComputerID | varchar(31) | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
| usageExpansion  | varchar(0)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageUser       | varchar(31) | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
| usageAddress    | varchar(28) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageGroup      | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageEvent      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageReason     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageTime       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageOtherTime  | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageGMTOffset  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| usageCount      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

Locate Description:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| computerID   | varchar(31) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| divisionName | varchar(24) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Programs Description:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| programID      | varchar(40) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| programName    | varchar(63) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| programVersion | varchar(31) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Writing to disc is much slower than reading from memory, that could be the bottleneck.  How long does the query take if you output to console instead of a CSV?

Comment: Your index probably won't be used since you're not filtering on `computerID`.  This is discussed on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes.  What does `EXPLAIN PLAN` show you about this query?

Comment: One last note: your query would be easier to read, and harder to accidentally break, with consistent aliases.  Having to look between the query and your text to discover that `divisionName` is part of `locate` and `programName` is a field of `Programs` is needless friction.

Comment: The bottle next isn't due to the file IO.  After hours of running it doesn't actually have anything in the /tmp file.

About database: Trust me, this thing makes my eyes bleed.  It's an inherited database and has worse faults than you see...  In the schema every field starts with the table name.  It's called divisionName because I created a temporary table so I didn't have to join Divisions->Computer->records just to get the login location.

Comment: Legacy systems can be very painful.  So `locate` is a temp table?  Is populating it part of the long run time, or just the query you're showing?  Diagnosing a problem script is much like any other technical problem: strip out elements until you've isolated the specific problem.  With that in mind, what does `EXPLAIN PLAN` say?  Does it run OK if you just include `Programs` and `locate`?  If so, you might want to aggregate `records` and then join to the remaining two tables.

Comment: Show us the create table statement for both tables, information about how many records, and a explain off your query. problem is probably a disk temporary table that needs to hold your records and a sort based on a disk temporary table is slow really slow...

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: No, lowercased tables are the ones that I've made since the inherit.  I made locate to paid a computer ID to an actual location.  Before the records table had a computerID, I had to lookup the computerDivisionID from the Computer table. Then, get the divisionName from the Division table.  

It was just easier to create the new table then always doing the double join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create foreign keys from `RECORDS` to `PROGRAMS` ans `LOCATE` ( you don't mention if they exist ).
- Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`. After all `RECORDS` is the "strong" table in this query.
- Group by `R.usageProgramID` instead of `by ProgramName`.

---

```
select divisionName, programName, count(usageID) 
    from records R 
    left join Programs P 
        on P.programID=R.usageProgramID 
    left join locate L 
        on L.computerID=R.usageComputerID 
    where divisionName="umbrella"
    group by R.usageProgramID 
    order by programName asc
```

---

Another alternative is to try this:

```
select
    t.divisionName, P.programName, count(*) as total
from (
        select L.divisionName, R.usageComputerID
        from records R 
        left join locate L 
        on L.computerID=R.usageComputerID 
        where L.divisionName="umbrella"
      ) t 
    left join Programs P 
        on P.programID=t.usageProgramID 
group by
    group by P.programName
    order by P.programName asc
```

Since the absence of FK maybe not helping.

Comment: Not possible.  The tables aren't setup with support for foreign keys so that's out.  And each program has dozens of id's.

For some reason it was setup in a way that gives each version of an application a unique ID. Chrome for example has a few hundred...

Comment: @Jacobm001 Will not different versions of an application have unique program names anyway ? Also, are R.usageProgramID and R.usageComputerID indexed ?

Comment: No, the programNames are condensed and are not unique.  There is programVersion in the Program table that correlates what version it's at.

Yes the two fields are indexed.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Try the left join. The right join is doing things the other way around.

Comment: Will do.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I added another alternative you could try.

Comment: Thank you.  The first option worked well, it brought the query down to around 10 minutes.